# ¿Es correcto el uso del verbo en "Eres tú y los demás."?

Tags: verbos, número-gramatical

A pesar que se refiere a varias personas (tú y los demás), no he escuchado que se diga

> Son tú y los demás.
>    <sub>(o "**Sois** tú y los demás", atendiendo a diferencias regionales)</sub>

¿Es eso correcto?

Un ejemplo similar podría ser

> Tú tienes la culpa y los demás también.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En tu primer ejemplo, sería correcto el uso del verbo en segunda persona plural, siendo esta flexión o *son* o *sois* según región.

Es fácil verificarlo porque al cambiar la posición del verbo y sujeto no creo que quepa duda de la forma correcta:

- Tú y los demás <sup>**sois**</sup>/<sub>**son**</sub> guapos.
- <sup>**Sois**</sup>/<sub>**Son**</sub> guapos tú y los demás.

Es así porque se contempla como un sujeto coordinado, es decir, el sujeto es un conjunto formado de ti y de los demás.  Se puede, en cualquier de las oraciones (las dos mías o la tuya) reemplazar *tú y los demás* por *vosotros/ustedes* sin ningún cambio de sentido.

En tu segundo ejemplo, sería correcto el uso del verbo en segunda persona singular, porque no se trata de un sujeto coordinado, sino de oraciones coordinadas, la segunda de la cual tiene un verbo elidido.

- Tú tienes la culpa
  …y…
  los demás también (*la tienen*).

En este caso, reemplazar *tú* con *vosotros/ustedes* cambiaría el significado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No conocía los sujetos coordinados y no estaba seguro de la existencia de aquel verbo elidido.

Comment: No estoy seguro si tengo que hacer otra pregunta, pero si en español hablado digo "Eres tú... (pausa) y los demás", ¿sería correcto?

Comment: @Kookoriko en este caso, normalmente, se lo entendería como «Eres tú alguien/algo... y los demás (*¿quiénes son?*)».  Si interpusieses otra palabra, sería posible una corrección tardía: «Eres tú alguien/algo… digo, y los demás», pero en tal caso no hace falta repetir toda la frase porque la corrección a «Sois/son tú y los demás» se entenderá.  Podría ser una buena pregunta sobre las correciones en el habla, eso sí, para otras cuestiones de concordancia.